how to save the cross-validation result in h2o ensmble?
h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = data_h2o,
                                base_models = list( rf_model,xgb_model, glm_model, nb_model, dl_model),
                                metalearner_algorithm = "glm",
                                metalearner_nfolds=5,
                                seed = seed)

Here is my code. It works well, and I can get the cross-validation summary, but I can't get the cross-validation result, the probability.
I have tried the parameter keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE but it has an error, which is not suitable for this function.
I have checked the parameter , but I can't find the corresponding one, could you please help me? cause i want to plot the roc curve for cross-validation result
